Getting DBus notifications of systemd service crashes?
I have linux application that consists of multiple processes, one of them is a "supervisor" process that takes actions if the others crash. All of the processes in the application are systemd services, and the supervisor is subscribed to the properties of each service via DBus. It monitors the ActiveState property. When it goes to failed crash handling actions kick in.
This works fairly good, but the problem is timing. When a process crashes a coredump is generated and this may take up to 30 seconds (it's an ARM system), and the ActiveState property only changes after the coredump is complete.
How can I get a notification of the crash event over DBus immediately (with service name)?
Things I tried:

checked all other properties of the object (on Service and Unit interfaces), but none of them change at the time of the crash
checked properties of the systemd Manager object, none of them are related
subscribed to UnitNew signal of the Manager object, with this I get notified of the coredump service start, but none of the coredump service properties indicate what has crashed exactly...

If it's possible I would like to keep systemd (via DBus) for getting information, and notification is preferred over polling.
Any idea?

Replace the systemd-coredump path in the kernel.core_pattern sysctl with a wrapper that would use libsystemd-bus or libdbus or busctl to send a D-Bus signal followed by execv()'ing the original systemd-coredump program (keeping the same argv).
With the default sysctl value:
kernel.core_pattern = |/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-coredump %P %u %g %s %t %c %h

the PID of the crashing process is provided as the first argument (%P). Use sd_pid_get_unit(3) to get the unit name (or read from /proc/PID/cgroup if you really don't want to use libraries).
